# Preloader em site Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Fala galera, não sou programador. Estou tentando colocar um preloader em meu site wordpress. Preciso que ele fique na tela por 2 segundos e depois suma. Não quero fazer com plugins.

Fiz tudo atraves de uma div no html, um css personalizado e um javascript. Tudo encontrei aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/SamirChaves/6ns0grm0/2/

O grande problema é que a animação fica carregando em um loop infinito. Podem me dizer o que fazer?

Não quero com plugin, pois toda vez que eu coloco o preloader com o plugin, ele desabilita meu anuncio ancora(fixo) do google adsense.

Answer (score -3):

Boa tarde, não sei se seria este o caso, mas dentro do css e do javascript tem a seguinte parte:

**CSS**
#loader .loader, #no-support .loader {
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
z-index: 100;
animation: jump .8s ease-in infinite;
}

**javascript**
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout('$("#preload").fadeOut(100)', 1500);

```
  });
```

Nesse caso verifica se esses campos controlam o tempo da aplicação.